# How to write a Shell Script to find Inputs/Output of a Function in a given file

Tags: bash, shell, search

I need to write a shell script which tells us all function names in a given file and their inputs/outputs

For Example consider the below file which has 2 functions. Each function has their input and output using getvalue and putvalue respectively.

```
static int function1()

{    
getvalue(session,"inp1",extra);    
getvalue(session,"inp2",extra);

------other code----------

putValue(session,"output1",extra);    
putValue(session,"output2",extra);

}

static int function2()   
{
getvalue(session,"inp3",extra);    
getvalue(session,"inp4",extra);

------other code----------

putValue(session,"output3",extra);   
putValue(session,"output4",extra);   
}
```

How do I write a script such that I can search the function name using "Static int" keyword and input/output of the function searching for "getvalue" and "putvalue" keyword within a function.

Output should be in below format.

```
Function Name :Function1
Input of Function :   
inp1    
inp2
Output Of Function:    
output1    
output2


Function Name :Function2
Input Of Function:    
inp3    
inp4

Output Of Function:    
output3  
output4
```

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange!  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish; non-working snippets of pseudocode with calls to undefined functions don't exactly make it clear....  Could you please edit your question and explain in plain English what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Re-phrased the question.

Comment: It took me a full minute to understand.  Now I get it.  **The "input" is the entire first code block, and the "output" is the entire second code block.**  The inclusion of "input" and "output" in the text of each of them is pure misdirection.

Comment: Yes. :)@Wildcard

Comment: @Wildcard Any idea on how to get this output??

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?  Just off the top of my head it looks like you should use a pair of arrays, one for function_inputs and one for function_outputs, iterate through the input file, then generate the output file.  `perl` is actually the tool for this kind of job, though you could probably do it in `bash`.  But you should write the code yourself, then come here for any specific syntax questions or debugging help you need.  We do like helping but not doing the work for you.

Comment: You could also use `awk` rather than `perl`; your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not 100% clear to me. But if you're asking how to replace inp by output you can do it using awk:

```
print "inp1" | awk 'sub(/inp/,"output")'
```

Comment: No i don't want to replace input with output. I have edited the question. PLease check again